# ObjectSet<Table>.Attach() issue

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I use following codes to update an entity:

```
    public int SaveCategory(Category category)
    {
        using (MyModel am = this.conn.GetContext())
        {
            if (category.CategoryId > 0)
            {
                am.Category.Attach(category);
                am.Category.ApplyCurrentValues(category);
            }
            else
            {
                am.Category.AddObject(category);
            }
            am.SaveChanges();
        }
        return category.CategoryId;
    }
```

This method, **adds** a copy of existing entity that I changed some of its value, but I want to update an existing entity.
What's my fault and/or what I missed out?
Thank you for your attention

Comment: What is the problem? Is it giving you any errors?

Comment: No error. All is ok, The problem is: I expect an update, but what is happened is add